Copy a worksheet using excel vba
I have a button that duplicates the current sheet and renames the new sheet based on user input
This works fine but when I try to have a certain cell in the new sheet become that value it changes the value in the original sheet not the new one.
Here's my code
    wNM = ActiveSheet.Name
    Worksheets(wNM).Copy After:=Worksheets(wNM)
    EMPN = Application.InputBox("Enter EMPN")
    
    ActiveSheet.Name = EMPN
    
    Range("H2").Value = EMPN

As you can see I can set activesheet to the value of EMPN and this works fine but when i try to set H2 to this value if sets it in the original sheet.
I have tried worksheet.activate but doesn't seem to do what i wish
Any help greatly appreciated!

Solved it by placing the code to generate a new sheet in a public function within a module rather than in the worksheet itself!
Button_click is in the worksheet and that calls the public module like so
'''
Button_click()
call new_sheet
'''
where new-sheet is a public module containing the code to copy the sheet

Your code is probably located in the worksheet module of the original worksheet. In that case, an unqualified range (like Range("H2")) is not referring to the active sheet but the sheet where the code is located.
Best is to never use unqualified ranges to avoid any such errors. Your code could look like this:
Worksheets(wNM).Copy After:=Worksheets(wNM)

Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Set newSheet = ActiveSheet
newSheet.Name = EMPN
newSheet.Range("H2").Value = EMPN

But I would even go a step further: Create a routine, eg CopySheet and put it into a regular module.
Sub CopySheet(sourceSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim EMPN As String
    EMPN = Application.InputBox("Enter EMPN")
    If EMPN = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    sourceSheet.Copy After:=sourceSheet
    
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = ActiveSheet
    newSheet.Name = EMPN
    newSheet.Range("H2").Value = EMPN
End Sub

Note that with this code, writing Range("H2").Value = EMPN would indeed refer to the active sheet - but take the few keystrokes to add the reference to a worksheet anyhow.
The event handler of the button just calls this routine:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CopySheet ActiveSheet
End Sub

